# importing data that is unique - c#/sql server solution

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

we periodically need to import a CSV that looks like this:

```
Name,SpecID,TestResult1,TestResult2,TestResult3
Alex,ASD123,3.23,452.2,232
Craig,DFG444,453.56,345.3,23
```

the data gets stored this way:

```
SPECIMENTABLE (name,specid,SPECIMENTABLEID)
Alex,ASD123,1
Craig,DFG444,2
```

and

```
    RESULTTABLE (testresult,result,SPECIMENTABLEID)
    TestResult1,3.23,1
    TestResult2,452.2,1
    TestResult3,232,1
    TestResult1, 453.56,2
    etc
```

im dumping the data like this:

```
    public void DumpQuickLabDump()
    {
        // T-SQL Connection
        string connection = "Data Source=gaia;Initial Catalog=SalesDWH;Integrated Security=True";


        // Get the data into the DataTable
        //dtData = GetData(...);

        // Create an object of SqlBulkCopy
        SqlBulkCopy objSBC = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
        // Specify the destination table
        objSBC.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        objSBC.BatchSize = 10000;
        objSBC.DestinationTableName = "SpecimenTable";
        // Write the data to the SQL Server

        objSBC.WriteToServer(QuickLabDump);
    }
    public void DumpTestResults()
    {
        // T-SQL Connection
        string connection = "Data Source=gaia;Initial Catalog=SalesDWH;Integrated Security=True";


        // Get the data into the DataTable
        //dtData = GetData(...);

        // Create an object of SqlBulkCopy
        SqlBulkCopy objSBC = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
        // Specify the destination table
        objSBC.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        objSBC.BatchSize = 10000;
        objSBC.DestinationTableName = "ResultTable";
        // Write the data to the SQL Server

        objSBC.WriteToServer(TestResults);
    }
```

sometimes the client will submit a CSV to me for uploading and then several days later, they will import another CSV but it will have a percentage of the SAME RECORDS.

how do i avoid duplicating the data? (please keep in mind that two tables are getting populated in the database from the one CSV file)

the solution can be .NET or sql.

thank you so much

Comment: Are you familiar with what a Delta is..? also sounds like you may need to alter your query to add SQL to check IfExist or NotExist depending on your logic to determine whether to update the row or rows I would suggest a Delta with a key field on a Date or TimeStamp because how would you know which is correct even if the date is current what if data was rolled back or changed accidently..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i would probably just do it on a combination of fields

Comment: @DJKRAZE no i dont know what delta is

Comment: Delta would be a way of taking the original value and comparing it with the new value.. kind of like :OldData vs :NewValue in Oracle my syntax is off but you get my drift.. Delta's are a way of determining if a field or fields can be updated or not..if the value is in a file but not in a database for example.. it's an ADD if the data value is in the database and it's in the file but the file has the updated data, then it's an Update.. if the Value is in the Database but not in the file then one would assume a Delete..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you want using `SqlBulkCopy` directly. You can however bulk copy the rows into a working table and then use a [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to either update or insert.

This does require however that your source information has enough information to uniquely identify each row.

Lets assume for example that instead of `SpecimenTable` was the `objSBC.DestinationTableName` it was set to `StagingSpecimenTable`. StagingSpecimenTablebeing a copy of the SpecimenTable struture. Then after the bulk copy you could execute this statement using a SqlCommand

```
MERGE SpecimenTable AS target
USING (SELECT name,specid FROM StagingSpecimenTable) 
     AS source (StagingSpecimenTable)
ON ( target.specid = source.specid )
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET target.mame= source.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT  (name, specid )
    VALUES (source.name, source.specid )
```

You'd then have to Delete or truncate StagingSpecimenTable as well a similar operation for ResultTable

Comment: +1 : SQLBulkCopy is specifically designed to "just do it" so as to be fast as possible.  The solution, therefor, is to bulk copy into holding tables, then run SQL that mopves them (as appropriate) into the main tables.

Comment: @conrad can you please show me how i would use merge to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need [Data deduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication) mechanism to detect which records was imported before, to do so you need to have a logic to be able to find dedupe records.

What is your logic? For instance you can set SpecID as your main Dedupe Rule, which means if your SpecID was same as data that you have in your database, then don't import it otherwise import it.

Or you can have combination of fields for your rule like "Name+SpecID" or even all fields to gather. In such cases I recommend using a helper field where you can store MD5 (Or any other hash mechanism) to store hash value of combining all your fields in your dedupe rule then before insert you need to generate hash for new values and check if it's already exist in your table by querying on your helper field.

This may be a little bit confusing but logic is really simple. Please let me know if you need more help on this :-)